# Laravel: Adding video dimension validation

Tags: php, validation, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I am aware that we can add dimension validations for an image in laravel by,

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), 
        [
            'banner' => 'bail
                        |image
                        |mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg
                        |max:7000
                        |dimensions:ratio=170/63
                        |dimensions:min_width=510,min_height=189'
        ]
    );
```

I have tried these dimensions rules for a video, but it doesn't seems to be working.

Is it possible to attain the same for a video?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about making your own rule? Exists a library via composer that read metadata of your video file called [getID3](https://github.com/JamesHeinrich/getID3).

Install it:

```
composer require james-heinrich/getid3
```

Create the custom rule class:

```
php artisan make:rule VideoDimension
```

Create the rule's logic with help of getid3:

```
<?php

namespace App\Rules;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;

class VideoDimension implements Rule
{
    protected $maxWidth;
    protected $maxHeight;

    public function __construct($maxWidth, $maxHeight)
    {
        $this->maxWidth = $maxWidth;
        $this->maxHeight = $maxHeight;
    }
    /**
     * Determine if the validation rule passes.
     *
     * @param  string  $attribute
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return bool
     */
    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        $getID3 = new getID3;

        // the value is an instance of UploadedFile
        $file = $getID3->analyze($value->getRealPath());

        $passes = true;

        if ($this->maxWidth < $file['video']['resolution_x']
            || $this->maxHeight < $file['video']['resolution_y']){
            $passes = false;
        }

        return $passes;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation error message.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function message()
    {
        return 'The :attribute excess the dimensions.';
    }
}
```

Finally, apply the rule:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), 
    [
        'video' => ['bail',
                    'file',
                    'max:7000',
                    new VideoDimension(400, 600)]
    ]
);
```

Hopefully this example help you to figure out how to achieve your task.